# Change tooltip position if outside the browser window

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am trying to make a function to change the tooltip position if it's outside the browser window. However, it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
function tooltipPosition (tooltip, x, y) {
    var tooltipX = x+20;
    var tooltipY = y;

    var offY = $(document).scrollTop();
    var offX = $(document).scrollLeft();

    var bottom = y + $(tooltip).height() + 10;

    if (bottom > $(window).height() + offY) {
        tooltipY = y + $(window).height() + offY - bottom;
    }

    $(tooltip).css('left', tooltipX);
    $(tooltip).css('top', max(tooltipY));
}
```

I think the problem is in the following line :

```
var tooltipX = x+20;
```

When I tried debugging it with firebug, the argument tooltipX value is "0px10" and not "10px". What can I do to make it work?

By the way, x and y are the left and the top value of the hovered div.

Comment: Seems your logic is pretty much there.  What exactly are x and y when they enter the function?  Are they strings such as `10px` or integers such as `10` ? You seem to be handling the `bottom` fine but you're making the x go further right if anything at all.

Comment: Here's a fiddle for folks to play with.  Don't have your `max` function though? http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/W93d5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to either convert `x` to integer or make sure `x` is integer before adding them together. Looks to me you are getting a invalid string for css in `tooltipX`.

Try:

```
function tooltipPosition (tooltip, x, y) {
    var tooltipX = parsetInt(x.split('px')[0])+20;
...
```

Comment: beware though this only works for css with 'px', you will need to adjust so that it checks all the possibility. Glad it helped.